# Program will not run after being installed by Windows Installer

Tags: windows-installer

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. When I run my application from within studio, it runs fine, when I use the setup package i created to install it to the Program Files(x86) folder, it doesn't do anything but generate an error in the application log that it connot create the file in this location because of an  System.UnauthorizedAccessException.
This is an SQLite db3 file that will be written to and needs to be created. Where do I put the file, and how do I do it in the setup project?

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because you are trying to save the application date next to your application binary, which is most likely located in Program Files.

Follow MSFT recommendations and update the application to [save the data in the recommended locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517940/windows-application-data-directory). This involves changes in your application code, not in the installer, because the data folder is created when you run the application, not the installer.